# How to find closest rounded number to a given value with certain properties?

Tags: python, python-3.x

With a given value `dividers_rough`, `dividers_scale` will be `int(x)` when `10^int(x)` is the highest possible value under `dividers_rough`.

For example: if `dividers_rough=3580` then `dividers_scale=3` and if `dividers_rough=0.021` then `dividers_scale=-2`.

Using `dividers_rough` and `dividers_scale` I need to find the closest number to `dividers_rough` which when it's divided by one of the numbers 1, 2, 5, or 10, gives me a value which can be expressed like - `10^int(n)`.

I tried to complete it and it works but only when `dividers_rough > 0.1`.
This is the code:

```py
optional_dividers = [abs((i*(10**dividers_scale))-dividers_rough) for i in [1, 2, 5, 10]]
finale_dividers = (
    [1, 2, 5, 10][optional_dividers.index(min(optional_dividers))] * 10**dividers_scale
)
```

(`finale_dividers` is what I'm trying to find.)

If you find the problem please write it.

Answer (score 0):

The [power operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) (aka exponentiation) in Python is `**` not `^` as it is in many other programming languages — so that's probably the problem.

This means you should use `10**int(n)`.